# Saving data to database using a modal

Tags: php, yii2, bootstrap-modal

I have a problem.

I need to open a modal to insert data in a table in the form of another table.

I can open a modal using Ajax with the view of the create view using the actionCreate from the controller, but when i clic save in the modal, the controller redirect me to the action view by default, and if i chage that, it open the full view in the current tab.

The problem was temporary resolved by making a redirect to the view that the modal should be in the if condition, but when i test to insert invalid data, the view render full-windowed with the message errors (in ajax render).

Also, the data always is save.

I know there's a way to render it in the modal without change view, but i'm new and not have any experience working with modals.

Need your help please.

There's my view file:

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use yii\bootstrap\Modal;
use yii\helpers\Url;
use app\models\Catalogo;


/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\Articulo */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
?>

<div class="articulo-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id'=>'articuloCreate']); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'ID_CATALOGO')->dropDownList(
        ArrayHelper::map(Catalogo::find()->all(),'ID_CATALOGO','NOMBRE_CATALOGO'),
        [
            'style'=>'width:500px',
            'prompt'=>'Seleccionar catálogo',  
        ]); ?>
    <?= Html::button('Agregar catálogo', [                        
        'value' => Url::to(['catalogo/create']),
        'class' => 'btn btn-primary',
        'id' => 'BtnModalCatalogo',
        'data-toggle'=> 'modal',
        'data-target'=> '#catalogo',
      ]) ?>
   <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

The modal in the same view:

```
<?php                 
    Modal::begin([
            'header' => 'Crear catálogo',
            'id' => 'catalogo',
            'size' => 'modal-md',
        ]);
    echo "<div id='modalContent'>BtnModalCatalogo</div>";
    Modal::end();
?>
```

There's more code, but i think is pointless putting it.

This is my JS:

```
$('#BtnModalCatalogo').click(function(e){    
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#catalogo').modal('show')
        .find('#modalContent')
        .load($(this).attr('value'));
   return false;
});
```

And this is the action create in the controller:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Catalogo();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->ID_CATALOGO]);
    }

    if(Yii::$app->request->isAjax){
            return $this->renderAjax('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }

    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

Just in case, this is the action view:

```
public function actionView($id)
    {
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        ]);
    }
```

First of all, thanks.

At the beggining, i expectet that the controller should load any other views in the modal, but not was like that.

Answer (score 0):

This action only responds when the action is called via ajax and will only redirect if the model is saved.

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Catalogo();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        if($model->save()) return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->ID_CATALOGO]);
    }

    return $this->renderAjax('create', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);

}
```